# Improving BFS performance with some kind of memoization

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have this issue that I'm trying to build an algorithm which will find distances from one vertice to others in graph.

Let's say with the really simple example that my network looks like this:

```py
network = [[0,1,2],[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[6,7]]
```

I created a BFS code which is supposed to find length of paths from the specified source to other graph's vertices

```py
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

n = 8
graph = {}

for i in range(0, n):
    graph[i] = []

for communes in communities2:
    for vertice in communes:
        work = communes.copy()
        work.remove(vertice)
        graph[vertice].append(work)

for k, v in graph.items():

    graph[k] = list(chain(*v))

def bsf3(graph, s):
    matrix = np.zeros([n,n])
    dist = {}
    visited = []
    queue = [s]
    dist[s] = 0
    visited.append(s)
    matrix[s][s] = 0

    while queue:

        v = queue.pop(0)
        for neighbour in graph[v]:

            if neighbour in visited:
                pass
            else:

                matrix[s][neighbour] = matrix[s][v] + 1


                queue.append(neighbour)
                visited.append(neighbour)



    return matrix

bsf3(graph,2)
```

First I'm creating graph (dictionary) and than use the function to find distances.

What I'm concerned about is that this approach doesn't work with larger networks (let's say with 1000 people in there). And what I'm thinking about is to use some kind of memoization (actually that's why I made a matrix instead of list). The idea is that when the algorithm calculates the path from let's say 0 to 3 (what it does already) it should keep track for another routes in such a way that matrix[1][3] = 1 etc.

So I would use the function like bsf3(graph, 1) it would not calculate everything from scratch, but would be able to access some values from matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question - BFS already does use the distances from previous nodes for subsequent nodes. The only issue I see in your code at a glance is that `visited` should be a set, not a list.

Comment: But is there any option to make it faster? I have changed visited to set, but when I run this code at the network which has 5000 members the code works really slowly. So slow that i'm not eveb sure if it is going to produce any results or it just got broken.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing this not fully answer your question, but this is another approach you cabn try.

In networks you will have a routing table for each node inside your network. You simple save a list of all nodes inside the network and in which node you have to go. Example of routing table of node D

```
A -> B
B -> B
C -> E
D -> D
E -> E
```

You need to run BFS on each node to build all routing table and it will take `O(|V|*(|V|+|E|)`. The space complexity is quadratic but you have to check all possible paths.

When you create all this information you can simple start from a node and search for your destination node inside the table and find the next node to go. This will give a more better time complexity (if you use the right data structure for the table).